# Scan from Postgres into struct with pointers

Tags: postgresql, go

What would be the benefit of using a struct like below with pointers instead of a struct without pointers when scanning from database?

```
  type User struct {
      ID           *UserID    `json:"id,omitempty"`
      Email        *string    `json:"email"`
      Username     *string    `json:"username"`
      PasswordHash *[]byte    `json:"password_hash"`
      CreatedAt    *time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    }
```

Comment: Counter-question: how would you scan a nullable-string value from your database into the `string` type?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark with `sql.NullString` in Go or with `COALESCE` in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Luke hinted, if you try to scan a row with null DB values into non-pointer types, the row-scan operation will result in an error.

Best practice is to examine the schema of the DB table. If columns cannot have null-values, use a non-pointer. If a null is possible (however remote a possibility you may think) use a pointer.

If you find pointers tedious to work with (i.e. boilerplate nil checks) use, say a, [sql.NullString](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) for a column field. If a NULL is encountered during a row-scan, a `NullString` value will default to an empty string.

Go 1.13 also added [`NullTime`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullTime)
etc. to handle other Nullable column types.

Answer (score 1):

Using a struct with pointers when scanning an unmarshaling is necessary if you need to distinguish between zero-values and null values. A string/int/struct will fail (or initialized to zero-value when unmarshaling) when the corresponding value is null, whereas a pointer to string/int/struct will be set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `pgx` as mentioned [at the end of the `lib/pg` README file on Github](https://github.com/lib/pq):

> For users that require new features or reliable resolution of reported bugs, we recommend using pgx which is under active development.

Then, you could use [custom pgtype](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype) instead of Go built-in ones.